# Using MVC5 Repository pattern but need advice on where to put business logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

My latest MVC solution consists of an MVC5 site and a DAL class library that will contain a repository interface and class for each entity. I am trying to figure out where to place business logic for my entities such as CheckingAccount.Withdrawl or CheckingAccount.Deposit. Any suggestions? Should this be done within the Model folder within the MVC project while all of the repository classes are in my DAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you want to separate your actual business logic from your entities and abstract it away from your database or ORM as much as possible by creating a business logic layer and injecting your repository into your service/business logic layer using an IoC container and [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

The common approach is to create a separate class library for your business logic layer that remains agnostic of your UI layer (meaning your UI layer could be an MVC front end or even restful web service) and communicates via  data transfer objects.

Here is a simple example:

**MVC Controller / UI**

```
public class AccountCheckingController : Controller
{

    private readonly IAccountService AccountService;

    public CheckingAccountController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        this.AccountService accountService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deposit(decimal depositAmount)
    {
        ...
        DepositReceiptDto depositReceipt = this.accountServive.Deposit(accountId, depositAmount);
        ...

        return new DepositViewModel {
            Receipt = depositReceipt
        }
    }

}
```

**Business Logic Class / Service** (stored in a class library such as `WebsiteName.Services` or `Website.BusinessLogic`

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{

    private readonly IAccountRepository Repository;

    public AccountService(IAccountRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }

    public DepositReceiptDto Deposit(int accountId, decimal depositAmount)
    {
        // Perform actions against your repository/ORM here.

        return new DepositReceiptDto {
            DepositAmount = depositAmount,
            User = UserDto,
            Status = Status.Success
        };
    }

    ...

}
```

As you can see, by using this separation you can easily switch out your UI without having to perform  much work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer. Let me try and get this straight: Make a solution with an mvc project, DAL(class library), BAL (class library). The DAL will contain my repository interfaces and classes for each entity. The BLL will reference the DAL and have a class/service for each entity or entity group and use the repositories to do what has to be done. Then finally only reference the DAL and the BLL from the MVC project.

Comment: and use dependency injection to passing the service/class I need to use to the controller through a constructor.  I guess that leaves me with one final concern.Wouldn't I reference just the BLL from my MVC project and in the BLL will be all business logic? Would the BLL also contain functions for common repository functions such as insert update getlist delete? This is where the confusion comes in: does the MVC project access just the BLL if so then how do I use my repository functions in my controller if needed.

Comment: You're correct; however the UI layer (in this case the MVC project) shouldn't reference the database layer. The UI layer references the business logic layer only and the business logic layer references the database layer only.

You shouldn't be injecting repositories into your controllers, controllers talk to the services/business logic classes.

Comment: The pattern I describe here is a a typical n-tier application structure. There are no hard and fast rules about the overall setup as it's a case of what works for you or your project. This is just a common example of how it's often setup. Any more questions then feel free to ask!

Comment: Even though we use these layers without IoC at work in our Webforms apps I'm still a little confused with the concept. Is there any chance you can put together a very small example using a simple Entity like Customers (the one above is great but doesn't take me all the way). UI(MVC5) --> BLL --> DAL(EF6) using dependency injection and EF6 code-first. I have Googled for the past couple of hours and just can't seem to put something together. I feel like once I get a good structure down for one of the entities I can follow it all the way through and learn additional things along the way.

Comment: I put a sample model together based on Pro MVC5 Apress book and examples on Google. It seems like the book has me only create 2 projects (Domain, WebUI). Please see the pics below. Will there be any use for the MVC Models folder anymore? Domain1: [link]http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=21a2dd5 Domain2: [link]http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=4147b62 Domain3: [link]http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=583d6da WebUI1: [link]http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=9e0fa90 WebUI2: [link]http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e4fca21

Comment: As mentioned in one of my earlier comments, there are many approaches and pattenrs to laying out a web application. The pattern that I describe is a standard n-tier application that's often used within enterprise environments. It sounds like the one you're referencing is a domain driven approach. Both have their pros and cons

Comment: Things are still a little unclear to me and I'm in the process of designing a template that is going to be used for several mvc projects down the road. I can't find any good examples on codeplex or github that have a simple example of a MVC, BLL, DAL project structure using dependency injection. Are there any that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

If something is not an entity and is not a value object, then it's a service. Correct namespace for service depends on his level. Data-access services may be located in the `Project.Dal` or `Project.Dal.Services`. The good namespace for domain's service is the `Project.Domain.Services`.